# How do we adjust the size/inset of an RCTRootView in ReactNative for iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I'm having trouble resizing the RCTRootView in iOS.

Setting the frame height and origin doesn't have any effect to the view.

Anyone know how to adjust the size or layoutMargins of a RCTRootView?

Comment: Can you post some code or any image file

Comment: Is the view that you put it in correctly sized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you cannot do this if you loaded your RCTRootView in:

```
- (void)loadView {
...
}
```

Proper way to do it is:

```
// SomeViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [...]
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:appName
                                            initialProperties:props];
  rootView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.width, 200);
  [self.view addSubview:rootView];
}
```

As referenced in: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/communication-ios.html

Answer (score 0):

Use constraints and use this -> `rootView.sizeFlexibility = RCTRootViewSizeFlexibility.widthAndHeight` or directly `set Frame` of the `RCTRootView`.